# Open file in a separate pane with a keyboard shortcut in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a keyboard shortcut to open the current file in vertical and/or horizontal split view in IntelliJ?

I know that I can <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when I select the file in the Project explorer, but I'd more or less like to move the currently open file into a new pane without having to go to the Project explorer first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign custom shortcuts for `Split and Move Right` and `Split and Move Down` actions in Keymap settings:
[image]

Comment: And now a shortcut to move the open file left or right, and I would be happy :) Unfortunately, there's only "Move to opposite group", which is not exactly what I want. But thx, anyway. Good enough for a start.